# Image slider with stacked cells

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing a web application which has a design that requires an scrolling div with stacked images (see image)

[image]

I have written the following HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
        <div class="item-image-craousel-left"></div>
        <div class="item-image-carousel">
            <div style="background-image: url('http://img2.timeinc.net/people/i/2014/stylewatch/blog/140915/blake-lively-600x450.jpg')" class="main-image"></div>
            <div style="background-image: url('assets/images/tumblr_ma7gmzwfAq1r780z3o1_250.jpg')" class="sub-image"></div>
            <div style="background-image: url('assets/images/tumblr_ma7gmzwfAq1r780z3o2_250.jpg')" class="sub-image"></div>
            <div style="background-image: url('assets/images/tumblr_ma7gmzwfAq1r780z3o3_250.jpg')" class="sub-image"></div>
            <div style="background-image: url('assets/images/tumblr_ma7gmzwfAq1r780z3o4_250.jpg')" class="sub-image"></div>
            <div style="background-image: url('assets/images/tumblr_ncdgtvSlUc1rjtt9yo2_1280.jpg')" class="sub-image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-image-craousel-right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.item-image-carousel {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-x: auto; 
}

.item-image-craousel-left {
    height: 399px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #40d1b0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 166px;
    display: none;
}
```

And currently I am getting this which is not overflowing and when I increase the width the images stack inline rather than in blocks of two as in the image above

[image]

Can someone tell me how I can achieve the layout as in the first picture. I am using Bootstrap 3 for its grid.

Comment: I'm not sure about Bootstrap but surely if it provides a grid module then you can use that to define a grid for the images too, within the main 'row' and 'col' elements? Grids are designed to be nestable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment I meant something like this...(not knowing the correct 'col-md-xx' to use)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
        <div class="item-image-craousel-left"></div>
        <div class="item-image-carousel row">
            <div class="col-md-8 main-image" style="background-image: url('http://img2.timeinc.net/people/i/2014/stylewatch/blog/140915/blake-lively-600x450.jpg')"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div style="background-image: url('assets/images/tumblr_ma7gmzwfAq1r780z3o1_250.jpg')" class="sub-image"></div>
                <div style="background-image: url('assets/images/tumblr_ma7gmzwfAq1r780z3o2_250.jpg')" class="sub-image"></div>
                <div style="background-image: url('assets/images/tumblr_ma7gmzwfAq1r780z3o3_250.jpg')" class="sub-image"></div>
                <div style="background-image: url('assets/images/tumblr_ma7gmzwfAq1r780z3o4_250.jpg')" class="sub-image"></div>
                <div style="background-image: url('assets/images/tumblr_ncdgtvSlUc1rjtt9yo2_1280.jpg')" class="sub-image"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-image-craousel-right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```